# Polimorfismo: cálculo del área y perímetro

Tags: c#

El control no puede quedar fuera del modificador de la etiqueta de caso final `(case consolekey.c)` ?

Estoy haciendo un programa que me permita calcular el área y el perímetro de las 
figuras geométricas (cuadrado, círculo, triángulo, cubo)   resumir

Me pueden ayudar con esa inquietud

### Program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo op, sop;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear(); //limpiar la pantalla
            Console.WriteLine("MENU PRINCIPAL");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("[C]Cuadrado");
            Console.WriteLine("[T]Triangulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[L]Circulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[R]Rectangulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[B]Cubo");
            Console.WriteLine("[ESC]Salir");

            op = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (op.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.C:
                    Cuadrado obj = new Cuadrado();
                    do
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("SUBMENU DEL CUADRADO");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("[1] Ingresar datos");
                        Console.WriteLine("[2] Calcular Area");
                        Console.WriteLine("[3] Calcular perimetro");
                        Console.WriteLine("[ESC] Regresar el Menu Principal");
                        Console.WriteLine("seleccione opcion");
                        sop = Console.ReadKey(true);

                        switch (sop.Key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("SUBMENU DEL CUADRADO");
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine("Escriba el valor del lado del cuadrado");
                                string v = Console.ReadLine();
                                obj.setvalor(double.Parse(v));
                                break;

                            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("El area del cuadrado es: " + obj.getArea());
                                Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para continuar...");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("Escriba el valor del lado del cuadrado");
                                string c = Console.ReadLine();
                                obj.setvalor(double.Parse(c));

                        }
                    } while (op.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Cuadrado

```
public class Cuadrado : FiguraGeometrica
{
    public Cuadrado() : base() { }

    public override void setvalor(double pvalor)
    {
        valor1 = pvalor;
    }
    public override double getArea()
    {
        return Math.Pow(valor1,2);
    }
    public override double getPerimetro()
    {
        return 4*valor1;
    }
}
```

Comment: pero cual seria el problema? no entendi lo del "(case consolekey.c) ?", podrias editar la pregunta y explicar un poco mas claro el punto que causa la duda

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el problema se presenta en la definición del `while`, si observas bien el código, verás que solo tienes un único `while`, pero dos `do`.

```
do
{
    //codigo
    do
    {
       //codigo
    }while (sop.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

} while (op.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

En el código lo resumo, pero debes evaluar las variables `op` y `sop` en los while, mientras que en el código que publicas solo evalúas una sola.

Cuando vas a tener muchos `switch` y `while` recomendaría lleves los ciclos a funciones - así no se hace tan largo el código.

Ejemplo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo op;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("MENU PRINCIPAL");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("[C]Cuadrado");
            Console.WriteLine("[T]Triangulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[L]Circulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[R]Rectangulo");
            Console.WriteLine("[B]Cubo");
            Console.WriteLine("[ESC]Salir");

            op = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (op.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.C:
                    CalcularCuadrado();
            }

        } while (op.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
}
```

allí defino la función `CalcularCuadrado()` que ayuda a llevar el otro `while` a una función separada:

```
private void CalcularCuadrado()
{
    Cuadrado obj = new Cuadrado();

    ConsoleKeyInfo sop;
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("SUBMENU DEL CUADRADO");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Ingresar datos");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Calcular Area");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Calcular perimetro");
        Console.WriteLine("[ESC] Regresar el Menu Principal");
        Console.WriteLine("seleccione opcion");
        sop = Console.ReadKey(true);

        switch (sop.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("SUBMENU DEL CUADRADO");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Escriba el valor del lado del cuadrado");
                string v = Console.ReadLine();
                obj.setvalor(double.Parse(v));
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("El area del cuadrado es: " + obj.getArea());
                Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para continuar...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Escriba el valor del lado del cuadrado");
                string c = Console.ReadLine();
                obj.setvalor(double.Parse(c));

        }
    } while (sop.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}
```